# docker-entrypoint.sh ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.backup

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to initialise a container running Postgres using

```
FROM postgres:9.6

COPY my.backup /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

in my Dockerfile

When I run, the output is:

```
root@pc ~ % docker run  -p 5432:5555 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
> This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
> The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
> The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
> creating subdirectories ... ok
> selecting default max_connections ... 100
> selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
> selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
> selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
> creating configuration files ... ok
> running bootstrap script ... ok
> performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
> syncing data to disk ... ok
>
> Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
> pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
>
> waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-10-09 00:41:58 UTC
> LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
> LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
> LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
> done
> server started
>
> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: **ignoring** /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.backup

I've checked file permissions

How can I determine why the init script is ignoring my backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `my.backup` is a shell script, you need to give it `.sh` extension. From [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.